# Flutter pop always from top to bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, push, transition, navigator

I would like to be able to always `pop` a `screen` *from top to bottom*. This is already working if I push like this:

```
static Route _createRouteWithBottomToTopTransition(Widget destinationPage) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => destinationPage,
      transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
        var begin = Offset(0.0, 1.0);
        var end = Offset.zero;
        var curve = Curves.ease;

        var tween =
            Tween(begin: begin, end: end).chain(CurveTween(curve: curve));

        return SlideTransition(
          position: animation.drive(tween),
          child: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

If I push with this `Route` I can simply call `Navigator.pop(context)` and the animation is as expected from top to bottom.

**Problem:** I don't always `push` with the customTransition. In some cases I simply push like this: `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page1')` because for `push` I want the standard slide in fro the right animation. But `page1` should still be `pop` from top to bottom. Is this possible? And if so, how? I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything.. I thought about creating a different `customPushTransition` but could not get a top to bottom animation...

Happy for every help! Let me know if you need more info!

Comment: This might be the way to go for you: https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition

Comment: @lrsvmb nice package, with this I can actually push from top to bottom but this looks actually not smooth at all :( What I need is the actual `pop`.